# Counting swaps and comparisons in an array method

Tags: java, loops, methods

I need help counting the swaps and comparisons i na selected bubble sort algorithm. I have tried passing in values to change them for each iteration but I cannot figure out how I can successfully implement a counter for the swaps and comparisons.

```
static void bubbleSort(int[] userArray_Copy, int n, int swaps) {
    swaps = 0;
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < n-1 ; j++) {
            if (userArray_Copy[j] > userArray_Copy[j + 1]){ 
                temp = userArray_Copy[j];
                userArray_Copy[j] = userArray_Copy[j+1];
                userArray_Copy[j+1] = temp;
                swaps++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is a purely pass-by-value language.  If you want to see how you changed `swaps`, you have to return its value.

Comment: @azurefrog I cannot use a return statement here friend

Comment: You can if you change the return type. Or update a static field. Or pass a mutable object that is updated, such as an AtomicInteger.

Comment: @DavidConrad This is very confusing. Must I change my method from static to something else?

Comment: No, `static` has nothing to do with it. `void` is the reason you can't return anything. If you want to track it by returning a value, change that, otherwise use one of the other approaches I mentioned.

Comment: Fyi, if you are trying to measure how fast the bubble sort is, there are somewhat faster implementation where the inner loop doesn't go every time up to n-1 (just Google bubble sort). You will still have O(n) complexity, it just reduces the comparisons by around half.